# How to change Firefox icon?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, icons

Is there any way to change Firefox system icon (the one on the left top of the window)?

Precision : I want to change the icon of a bundled version of Firefox with apache/php and my application. So manual operation on each computer is not a solution.
I try Resource Hacker and it's the good solution. The add ons one is good too.

Comment: I'm sure there is...but that is not an appropriate question t oask here unless it relates to programming some how.

Comment: Well, my question is about something I have to deliver to a customer, and I am a developer, so it is not programming but it's near to. No?

Comment: Be advised that you can't use the "Firefox" name if you change the icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resource hacker does the job of swapping application icons in Windows (up to XP, not tested with Vista yet).

Available at:
http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/

Answer (score 2):

@phloopy's good suggestion to use http://iconpacks.mozdev.org/ unfortunately doesn't work with newer versions of Firefox (I think to the omni.jar change). You can still use their ICO files (or your own), but you now need to do the following manual steps...

- Unzip `omni.ja` in your Firefox application directory.
- Delete `omni.ja` or rename it (e.g. `omni.ja.off`).
- Create directories `icons/default` in the Firefox `chrome` application directory.
- Copy the icon file you want to `chrome/icons/default/main-window.ico`
- Start Firefox and enjoy your new icon

Notes:

- There are other ICO file names you can use for other windows. The ones I have personally seen work are:

  - `main-window.ico` for browser windows and Scratchpad
  - `downloadManager.ico` for Downloads
  - If you know others please comment so I can add them. I personally would love one for Firebug and the Error Console. One for Library (Bookmarks) would be nice also (`bookmark-window.ico` does not work).
- Your start time will be a little slower (due to the unzipping of `omni.ja`). In theory you can jar it up again, but I am not 100% sure that will work once they get the `omni.ja` optimization working again (it's "broken" in Firefox 10 so `omni.ja` is actually normal JAR/ZIP file).
- If you let Firefox update you will need to do this again
- Note many zip tools cannot read Firefox’s variation on the JAR format (see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=605524).

More info is available at http://iconpacks.mozdev.org/docs/faq.html

Answer (score 1):

There are icon packs available at http://iconpacks.mozdev.org/ that work by installing an extension.  If you want to use your own icon, extensions are just zipped files so change the extension from xpi to zip and examine the source code and images it contains to customize it.  If you do customize it, I suggest changing the GUID that so it doesn't auto-update and overwrite your customizations.

Comment: A nice tip, unfortunately the installers are not working and there is no info on why or when it will be fixed. I suspect because of the change to omni.jar. I put the updated manual steps in a separate answer (can't format it well inside a comment).

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the system icon, not the site icon as someone else thought.  On a Mac, you can hold-Click -> Get Info on Firefox.app, then drag or paste an image on top of the icon.

I'm not sure about Windows, but I think you may need to compile from source to change it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the application icon (which under Windows is typically located in the top-left corner of the application's window), then... no... and yes.

Like most windows apps, the icon you see there is probably a resource compiled into the application itself, so you can't change it.

There may be add-ins to Firefox that let you do this, but I doubt it - that icon is trademarked and "identifies" the Firefox "brand" (if you will). So it's unlikely that you could change it at run-time.

Firefox is open-source; you could always just download & compile your own version, replacing the icon resource with your own. A bit dramatic, but possible.